# Script incompatibility for Python 2.x and Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I cannot understand what happens with python3 that prevents this from working, when I try with python3, it just hungs on line 11.

```
import io,re,unittest,os,json,sys
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT, Popen
sub = Popen(["/usr/bin/python3.4", "test2.py", "pipe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=sys.stderr, close_fds=True, shell=False)
(writer,reader) = (sub.stdin, sub.stdout)
writer.write("HELO\t1\n".encode("utf-8"))
writer.flush()
sub.poll()
line = reader.readline().decode("utf-8")
assert(re.match("^OK\t", line))
writer.write("Q\ttest.com\tIN\tSOA\t-1\t127.0.0.1\n".encode("utf-8"))
line = reader.readline().decode("utf-8")
assert(re.match("^DATA\ttest.com\tIN\tSOA\t300\t-1\tsns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2013073082 7200 3600 1209600 3600", line))
sub.stdout.close()
sub.stdin.close()
sub.kill()
sub.wait()
```

Here's the `test2.py` file that the above code calls:

```
import sys
sys.stderr.write(sys.stdin.readline())
sys.stdout.write("OK\tversion foo bar hello\n")
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stderr.write(sys.stdin.readline())
sys.stdout.write("DATA\ttest.com\tIN\tSOA\t300\t-1\tsns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2013073082 7200 3600 1209600 3600")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Please put a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) **in the question** (and read [what's new in 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)).

Comment: I could not reduce any more code in order to reproduce this issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, I reproduced your problem and fixed it by adding a `writer.flush()` after your second `writer.write()` call. E.g.:

```
import io,re,unittest,os,json,sys
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT, Popen
sub = Popen(["/usr/bin/python3.4", "test2.py", "pipe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=sys.stderr, close_fds=True, shell=False)
(writer,reader) = (sub.stdin, sub.stdout)
writer.write("HELO\t1\n".encode("utf-8"))
writer.flush()
sub.poll()
line = reader.readline().decode("utf-8")
assert(re.match("^OK\t", line))
writer.write("Q\ttest.com\tIN\tSOA\t-1\t127.0.0.1\n".encode("utf-8"))
writer.flush() # <<< INSERTED FLUSH <<<
line = reader.readline().decode("utf-8")
assert(re.match("^DATA\ttest.com\tIN\tSOA\t300\t-1\tsns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2013073082 7200 3600 1209600 3600", line))
sub.stdout.close()
sub.stdin.close()
sub.kill()
sub.wait()
sub.wait()
```

It now executes properly if the main script is run in Python 2 or Python 3 (tested: 2.7 and 3.4)

I say "on my system" because this sort of interleaved reader-writer coordination across text pipes is intrinsically fragile. When it works great, it's great! But very small variations in how the system, system libraries, language implementations, etc. handle I/O can cause you all manner of grief.

Comment: Reason for this is the default value for `bufsize` in `Popen` has changed. Used to be 0 (unbuffered), is now -1 (system default pipe buffer size). It looks like op should set `bufsize` to 1 (line buffered).

Comment: @Dunes Good insight! I didn't realize the buffering behavior had shifted. But it's a great example of the 'apparently subtle differences beget fragility' I rail against.